# Why is the default encoding in Rails not UTF-8?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

When I use UTF-8 characters (most of the time Turkish characters) in controllers, I have to add `#encoding: utf-8` on the top of each controller file.
Why doesn't Rails use this as a default?

edit: I have learnt that it is not about Rails, it is about Ruby.

Comment: It's the default encoding in Ruby 2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby 2.0 is UTF8 by default.  Otherwise you must signify that in 1.9.  According to naruse:

> The default script encoding change.
>
> Default script encoding (when magic comment is not specified) is
>   changed into UTF8[[#6679]](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6679) In Ruby 1.9, the default script encoding is
>   US-ASCII. We changed it to be UTF-8 after considering the following
>   pros and cons. UTF-8 default is convenient because the majority of
>   modern application uses UTF-8 This change doe not impact any 1.9 codes
>   if Magic Comments are in place. The default script encoding in 1.9
>   without Magic Comment is either US-ASCII or ASCII-8BIT. In UTF-8, then
>   some string manipulation could become slower.

Source: [Rubyist Magazine](http://jp.rubyist.net/magazine/?Ruby200SpecialEn-note)

Answer (score 1):

Rails is not a programming language. It is just library written in Ruby. It cannot change the fundamental syntax of Ruby. Ruby 1.8 doesn't know anything about encodings, in Ruby 1.9 the default is ASCII and in Ruby 2.0 the default is UTF-8. There's nothing Rails can do about it.