# rails regular expression validation string escape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

I have a name attribute in my model which is validated by

```
validates :name ,format:{with: /^[\p{L} \.'\-]+$/ , message: "invalid name" }
```

The following syntax error was found while creating an object of the model

```
SyntaxError (basic_info.rb:8: invalid  property name {L}: /^[\p{L} \.'\-]+$/
```

Apparently Ruby is trying to evaluate `{L}` inside the regex which is undefined. Also inserting escape characters inside the regex would make it invalid.

Comment: Try `\p{L}` instead of `\p\{L}`

Comment: It would help if you showed an example of a valid name, so we know what you're trying to do. Also, the regex in your error isn't the same as above it.

Comment: I tried the regex on www.rubular.com. Its working fine. Any name having alphabets only would work.

Comment: I don't know ruby, but `\pL` is correct in perl. Have you try it without braces?

Comment: No `\pL` doesn't seem to work in Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561365/why-is-the-default-encoding-in-rails-not-utf-8) it's to do with encoding. Pre-Ruby 2.0.0, the default encoding for ruby scripts is not Unicode, so this'll be causing you issues when using a unicode character property regexp pattern (`\p{L}` for example!).

You need to put the magic `# encoding: utf-8` comment at the top of your file.

---

I just did a quick IRB test, but are you using Ruby 1.8.7 by any chance?

In 1.8.7:

```
>> "blah".match(/^[\p{L} \.'\-]+$/)
=> nil
```

in 2.0.0:

```
>> "blah".match(/^[\p{L} \.\-']+$/)
=> #<MatchData "blah">
```

Seems 1.8.7 Regexp doesn't support unicode character properties? Consider using `/^[a-zA-Z \.'\-]+$/` instead.

Comment: No,but I tried `"blah".match(/^[\p{L} \.\-']+$/)` which returns `#<MatchData "blah">` as expected. I fail to understand why Rails is throwing a validation error while creation.